# Codeigniter do_upload doesn't response in production server

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I made a page that will upload certain file types.
It works fine in my local development but not in production.
It won't pass the do_upload() function. Nothing is displayed beyond that.

```
$path = 'uploads';
echo 'path: '. $path .' <br>'; 

//-- config for uplaod --
$configUpdload['upload_path']   = $path ;
$configUpdload['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|xls|xlsx|pdf';
$configUpdload['max_size']   = '4000'; //size in kilobytes
$configUpdload['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;

//-- load upload library --
$this->load->library('upload');

$this->upload->initialize($configUpdload);

if ($_FILES['fileref']['name']!="")
{
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    echo 'uploadAttachment<br>';

    $uploaded = $this->upload->do_upload("fileref");

    echo 'uploaded: '. $uploaded . '<br>';

    if ($uploaded == true)
    {
        echo 'uploaded data<br>';
        $inputUp = $this->upload->data();
        echo 'data: '. print_r($inputUp,true) . '<br>'; 
        $uploadInput['orig_name']   = $inputUp['orig_name'];
        $uploadInput['enc_name']    = $inputUp['file_name'];
        $uploadInput['extension']   = $inputUp['file_ext'];

        echo 'uploaded true<br>';
    }else{
        die($this->upload->display_errors());
    }
}
```

I tried changing the upload_path to non existing folder, it show 'The upload path does not appear to be valid'. Means the do_upload() does work right?

The uploads folder permission is 777.

I also tried using absolute path but still doesnt show anything pass do_upload().

Or anything to do with the server?

Does anyone knows what is happening? Help much appreciated.

Thanks.

[edit1]

Nothing in the server's error log nor normal log. I also set $config['log_threshold'] = 4; No error log.

[edit2]

Production server is 3rd party web hosting under linux. I tried php_info() and trace anything to do with upload.

```
file_uploads        On  On  
max_file_uploads    20  20  
pload_max_filesize  30M 30M  
upload_tmp_dir      /tmp/   /tmp/  
suhosin.upload.disallow_binary  0   0  
suhosin.upload.disallow_elf 1   1  
suhosin.upload.max_uploads  25  25  
suhosin.upload.remove_binary    0   0  
suhosin.upload.verification_script  no value
```

I also tried decrease the filesize $configUpdload['max_size']   = '10'; but no message after do_upload() still.

[Edit3]
My folder structure:

```
public_html/gtapp/
public_html/gtapp/csystem/ <- is system folder
public_html/gtapp/v1/ <- is application folder
public_html/gtapp/media/
public_html/gtapp/uploads/
public_html/gtapp/license.txt
```

In config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/gtapp/
```

In index.php:

```
$application_folder = 'v1';
```

when I do `APPPATH . 'uploads';` to above code is shows:

```
uploadAttachment
path: v1/uploads
uploaded: 
The upload path does not appear to be valid.
```

I tried `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/gtapp/uploads';` 
It just shows:

```
uploadAttachment
path: /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/gtapp/uploads
```

[Edit4]

I made a crude version of native PHP upload codes and it works. I dont think it is a server issue. Below is the code:

```
$name = 'fileref'; 

$upload_path    = './uploads/';
$allowed_types  = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "xls", "xlsx", "pdf");
$extension      = end(explode(".", $_FILES[$name]["name"]));
$max_size       = '4000';

if ($_FILES['fileref']['name']!="")
{
    if ((($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "application/excel")
        || ($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
        || ($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "application/msexcel")
        || ($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "application/pdf")
        || ($_FILES[$name]["type"] == "application/x-download"))
        && (round($_FILES[$name]["size"]/1024,2) < $max_size )
        && in_array($extension, $allowed_types))
        {

            if ($_FILES[$name]["error"] > 0)
            {
                echo $_FILES[$name]["error"]);
            }
            else
            {
                $uploadInput['orig_name']   = $_FILES[$name]["name"];
                $uploadInput['enc_name']    = sha1($_FILES[$name]["name"]);
                $uploadInput['extension']   = $_FILES[$name]["type"];

                $moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]["tmp_name"], $upload_path . $uploadInput['enc_name'] . '.' . $extension);

                if($moved)
                    echo 'success';
                else
                    echo 'fail';

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there's something in the error log that can help you debug the issue.

Comment: What webserver are you running? It could be your php.ini or your web server configuration refusing files over a certain size.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

@KemalFadillah. Nothing in the server's error log nor normal log. I also set $config['log_threshold'] = 4; No error log.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  
  
@Brendan. Im not sure what to look. Production server is 3rd party web hosting under linux. I tried php_info() and trace anything to do with upload.    

file_uploads  On On  
max_file_uploads 20 20  
pload_max_filesize 30M 30M  
upload_tmp_dir  /tmp/ /tmp/  
suhosin.upload.disallow_binary 0 0  
suhosin.upload.disallow_elf 1 1  
suhosin.upload.max_uploads 25 25  
suhosin.upload.remove_binary 0 0  
suhosin.upload.verification_script no value  
  
I also tried decrease the filesize $configUpdload['max_size']   = '10'; but no message after do_upload() still

Comment: Run `ps ax | grep httpd` on the command line. You can replace httpd with nginx as well if the only result is "grep httpd". This command shows running processes that match your grep pattern. Have you tried uploading a very small file?

Comment: I dont have remote access for the web hosting. May I know why I should do that? I have tried uploading small files hundred bytes but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with CI and trying to verify a files existance outside of app folder, and found that CI has this one enviromental veriable reserved for itself. APPPATH, it finds the core folder that CI is in, from the index.php level where you have your application and system folder. So if you try replacing `$configUpdload['upload_path']   = './uploads' ;` with `$configUpdload['upload_path']   = APPPATH.'uploads';`

you may run into a bit more luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response @chris. I tried `APPPATH.'uploads';` but it shows `The upload path does not appear to be valid.` using this the path is `v1/uploads` which is not true. my uploads is at `application/uploads` same hierarchy with v1. I also tried creating the uploads folder at that location but still blank after do_upload()

Comment: v1 I take it is your root directory for CI meaning if you go into v1 you will see "application", "system" "index.php" and maybe "License" and something else.. If this is correct then my first decleration was assuming your upload folder was also in the same line as those particular files/folders. and not within the application folder. If so far what I said about v1 is true, then try `$configUpdload['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'application/uploads';

Comment: I see, sorry I'm confusing everyone, just realized that my folder names are a bit different from the original. Yup, my uploads folder is the same line with application and system. I will edit the post for the folder structures. Please take a look in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once and all I did was to change the following:

Change:

```
$path = 'uploads';
$configUpdload['upload_path'] = $path ;
```

To:

```
$path = './uploads';
$configUpdload['upload_path'] = $path;
```

Or just:

```
$configUpdload['upload_path'] = './uploads';
```

Comment: and I just realized now that in your crude php code you used the path the way I recommended you and in CI's one you used it without it so that should fix the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

`$upload_path    = './uploads/';`

to

`$upload_path    = FCPATH.'uploads/';`

And it will work for you on production server as well.